# How do i properly initialize Room (AndroidViewModel)?

Tags: android, android-room, android-viewmodel

I am using a Room Database with `AndroidViewModel` (without Factory)

```
class RoomModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
        // ....
}
```

and I am not sure about how to correctly initialize that, and also if I could use one-time initialization for whole app.

I have two ways to deal with initializations which seem to work OK:

**Initializing in `onViewCreated()`:**

```
...
private lateinit var database: RoomModel
...
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        ...
        database = ViewModelProvider(this)[RoomModel::class.java]
        ...
}
```

**Initializing by `activityViewModels()`:**

```
...
private val mData: RoomModel by activityViewModels()
...
```

The both seem to work, but not sure which one would never lead to an app crash at some point.

Also, I would like to know, if it's a good practice using one shared reference variable of my `RoomModel` declared and initialized in a base Fragment that is used by other fragments like this:

```
class BaseFragment : Fragment() {
        ...
        lateinit var database: RoomModel
        // Or
        val database: RoomModel by activityViewModels()
        ...
        
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
                ...
                database = ViewModelProvider(this)[RoomModel::class.java]
                ...
        }
}
```

Some other fragments extended by `BaseFragment()` like this:

```
class FragmentA : BaseFragment() {
        ...
            
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            ...
            // use the reference variable database to observe or add or edit data
        }
}
```

and

```
class FragmentB : BaseFragment() {
        ...
            
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            ...
            // use the reference database to observe or add or edit data

        }
}
```

and so on...

In this way I have only to init the Room once and use it without reinitializing in each fragment I need to access to. Is that a good idea or rather do I need to use individual declaration and initialization of `RoomModel` in each Fragment I need access to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Room Database instance should be a singleton. The instance should live as long as the application itself. It is costly to initialize it every time you need to use it. You should initialize Room Database in the application and each `ViewModel` that needs Room Database instance will get it from the application as a dependency. Or you can provide the Room Database as a dependency to your `ViewModel`, but then you need to create a factory for your `ViewModel`. You can also use a Dependency Injection library to manage it for you, but it can be overwhelming at first.

Without using any dependency injection library, you can see the example below.

Override the `Application`, and don't forget to declare it in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

`AndroidApp.kt`

```
class AndroidApp : Application() {

    lateinit var myRoomDatabase: MyRoomDatabase

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        myRoomDatabase = Room
            .databaseBuilder(applicationContext, MyRoomDatabase::class.java, "my-room-database")
            .build()
    }
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
...
<application
        android:name=".AndroidApp"
...
>
...
```

When you extends the `AndroidViewModel` you have the `Application` instance as a dependency. Cast it to `AndroidApp` and now you can get `myRoomDatabase`.

`MainViewModel.kt`

```
class MainViewModel(app:Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
    private val myRoomDatabase = (app as AndroidApp).myRoomDatabase
    ...
}
```

`FragmentAViewModel.kt`

```
class FragmentAViewModel(app:Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
    private val myRoomDatabase = (app as AndroidApp).myRoomDatabase
    ...
}
```

`FragmentBViewModel.kt`

```
class FragmentBViewModel(app:Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
    private val myRoomDatabase = (app as AndroidApp).myRoomDatabase
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for giving me such a full answer. Do I understand it correctly? For each Fragment, I need to access Room from I need to create its own `AndroidViewModel`? Additionally, what kind of initialization for those `AndroidViewModel` classes for each fragment should I use, this one  `val fragmentBViewModel: FragmentBViewModel by activityViewModels()` or this one `lateinit var fragmentBViewModel: FragmentBViewModel` with `fragmentBViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[FragmentBViewModel::class.java]`? Thanks.

Comment: @MarkDelphi It depends on your use cases. If your `Fragment`s are in the same `Activity` and you want to share the `ViewModel`, you can get the activity's `ViewModel` by using the delegate function `val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()`. This way your fragments will get the same instance of `MainViewModel`. But if your fragments have different functionalities, it's best that you use different `ViewModel` for each `Fragment`. And you can also get the `ViewModel` inside a fragment using `val viewModel:FragmentBViewModel by viewModels()`.

Comment: I have only one Activity and the fragments have similar factionality (add, edit, remove rows in the Room). Therefore, the activityViewModels() should be enough. Thanks for your help.